# Installing X Protocol in order to use mysql shell - Mac

Tags: python, mysql, macos, shell

My aim is to connect a MySQL database to a python web scraper I have written.

I have started the process of installing mysql shell, which seems to be the correct version of mysql for my needs. I am following [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html#installing-xplugin-linux-quick) for downloading X Protocol and am stuck.

Following the instructions to download using MySQL Shell, it says

- navigate to the MySQL binaries location (for example, /usr/bin/ on Linux).
- Run the following command:

`mysqlsh -u user -h localhost --classic --dba enableXProtocol`\

Which when I run this command, after being promted to type in my password:

```
Creating a Classic Session to 'user@localhost'
Enter password:
```

I then receive this error:

```
ERROR: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (61)
```

How do I get around this situation?

P.s. I'm not sure if I should be entering 'user' or my actual username 'Frankie'

Answer (score 0):

Error message indicated that you don't have installed MySQL Server.
Firstly, you need to install or upgrade to MySQL 5.7.12 or higher. How to do it is described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html